# What happens when a pthread dies while waiting on a mutex?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

If a process has three threads, T1, T2, and T3, and all three try to acquire a lock on mutex M1, I understand that one will acquire the mutex and the other two will wait until they acquire the mutex.

If I use the pthread_mutexattr_setrobust() to make the threads robust, then I understand that if T1 holds M1, and T1 terminates before releasing, M1, T2 is woken with the return value of EOWNERDEAD.  T2 then can clean up the state of the protected resource.

Now, what happens if T1 owns M1 while T2 and T3 are waiting on M1.  T2 is terminated.  What happens?  When T1 releases M1, does the mutex go straight to T3?  Does T3 get the EOWNERDEAD, or does it just look to T3 like nothing ever happened and there is no cleanup required?  It seems like it T3 should just take M1 because T2 couldn't have gotten the thread into an inconsistent state.  Any answers?  This is a question of intellectual interest for me rather than trying to solve a particular problem, so pointers to further reading on this subject would be appreciated.

EDIT: I am not trying to figure out how to do it right, instead I am trying to figure out what happens, in general for pthread implementations, when T2 is either terminated or is canceled (interested in both cases, and only starting to understand the difference it might make to the outcome).  Is it defined behavior?

My target platform is Windows using the Windows Services for Unix in case it is platform dependent, but my interest is general in what is supposed to happen.   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463209.aspx.

Comment: Windows doesn't have pthreads, please edit your question to clarify the context.  Is your target platform really Cygwin, perhaps?  Or are you using a third-party library such as pthreads-win32?

Comment: ... in any case, the correct answer is almost certainly that terminating T2 results in undefined behaviour, because terminating a thread on Windows pretty much *always* results in undefined behaviour.  Just don't.

Comment: If you are using pthreads-win32, note that `pthread_kill` [is specifically documented](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/conformance.html) "only supports zero sig value, for thread validity checking".

Comment: Robust mutexes are only interesting if you have a process-shared mutex, since forcing threads to terminate is inherently dangerous. If you use pthread_cancel(), you should use cancellation state and cleanup handlers to fix state and unlock mutexes before exiting the thread. (pthread_kill() does not terminate a single thread unless you have a signal handler that calls pthread_exit(), which is rather dangerous.) As pthreads-win32 does not seem to support process-shared mutexes, this makes the whole question less interesting.

Comment: @jilles I think you are almost giving me the exact answer I am looking for.  If I use pthread_cancel() on T2, and fail to do anything else, what happens to the mutex when T1 releases?

Comment: The fact that pthread_mutex_lock [isn't a cancellation point](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cancel) may be relevant.  It seems unlikely that pthreads-win32 implements asynchronous cancellation, though SFU might.  I don't know whether SFU supports process-shared mutexes.  It's quite an obscure technology.  I'm afraid you may not have much luck finding anyone familiar with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: I am basing this answer entirely on the standards as written, not on personal experience or relevant expertise.*

Cancelling a pthread divides into two cases:

If the pthread is configured for deferred cancellation (this is the default) then according to a literal reading of the standard the cancellation request won't be processed until after the mutex has been claimed (or failed to be claimed) since `pthread_mutex_lock` and friends are not on the list of functions that are cancellable as shown [in section 2.9.5 of the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_01).

I am not certain whether the various implementations actually behave this way, since it seems undesirable.  If an implementation does in fact permit cancellation while attempting to claim a mutex (perhaps because the `pthread_mutex_lock` function internally uses one of the listed cancellable functions) I would expect it to result in the mutex remaining consistent and unclaimed as per Jille's answer, but the standard does not appear to require it explicitly.

If the pthread is configured for async cancellation, the behaviour is undefined:

> The pthread_cancel(), pthread_setcancelstate(), and pthread_setcanceltype() functions are defined to be async-cancel safe.
>
> No other functions in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 are required to be async-cancel-safe.
>
> If a thread has asynchronous cancellation enabled and is cancelled during execution of a function that is not async-cancel-safe, the behavior is undefined.

It does not appear to be possible to terminate a single pthread.  From [section 2.4.3:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04)

> When a signal is delivered to a thread, if the action of that signal specifies termination, stop, or continue, the entire process shall be terminated, stopped, or continued, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use condition variables to make it perfectly work. I copy pasted some documentation below.

Condition variables allow threads to synchronize to a value of a shared resource. Typically, condition variables are used as a notification system between threads.

For example, you could have a counter that once reaching a certain count, you would like for a thread to activate. The thread (or threads) that activates once the counter reaches the limit would wait on the condition variable. Active threads signal on this condition variable to notify other threads waiting/sleeping on this condition variable; thus causing a waiting thread to wake. You can also use a broadcast mechanism if you want to signal all threads waiting on the condition variable to wakeup. Conceptually, this is modeled by the figure on the right with pseudocode.

When waiting on condition variables, the wait should be inside a loop, not in a simple if statement because of spurious wakeups. You are not guaranteed that if a thread wakes up, it is the result of a signal or a broadcast call.

documentation link: http://randu.org/tutorials/threads/

Answer (score 1):

Per the specification of `pthread_mutex_lock()` from POSIX.1-2008tc1:

- A thread becomes the owner of a mutex if `pthread_mutex_lock()` returns zero or `[EOWNERDEAD]`.
- The error `[EOWNERDEAD]` occurs when the process containing the owning thread (or, optionally, the owning thread) terminated while owning the mutex.

In your example, `pthread_mutex_lock()` does not succeed for T2, and therefore T3 will acquire M1 without error.

Comment: Are you certain that the implementation actually conforms to the standard this closely?  The OP hasn't even specified what implementation they're using.

Comment: Does the standard define what should happen here?  I am much less interested in the particular platform than what *should* happen.  I would love a pointer if possible.